# How to implement the tracing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to use JavaScript to implement the tracing?  Any suggestions or help will be much appreciated.

[image: for your reference, Please check this link]

Comment: please explain tracing - not sure what you mean.

Comment: initially closed polygon is drawn in the canvas,after that User has to draw /drag his finger on the polygon without lifting his finger. Tracing in the sense user has to draw/Drag on the polygon edges exactly on the polygon as it is.